# What can I use to scrape data from WFS or ideally WMS?

Tags: gis

I'm looking to see if it's possible to extract data from WFS or ideally WMS.

Here is an example dataset:

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/b5d8eaa4-638c-436b-a66c-a6bd1a25f0df/historic-landfill-sites

The goal is to be able to access a WMS, use a mapping co-ordinate (latitude/longitude) to locate an area of interest, then extract whether the coordinate is present in a historic landfill site or not. If true, it would then collect the landfill data. Preference would be through the Python language but open to anything.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and can provide any extra information or clarity if required.